# WooCommerce checkout minimum order based on city

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, minimum, orders

I am new to woocommerce so I need you help to findout the issue i am trying to solve from last 3 days. In short, I have a pizza store at 5 locations. There is a minimum order per location. In checkout I made a custom city select option field based on it total bill will be accepted or rejected. I am using checkout manager. Its really confusing. 
So my question is how can I do this and achieve this result. I don't want to hard code everything because In future locations might change.

Any solution for this problem. Thanks In advance.

Comment: _"I don't want to hard code everything because In future locations might change."_ - well then store them in the database instead ...

Comment: there is another reason I don't know much php

Answer (score 2):

```
function check_min_order($order_id) {
         global $woocommerce;

         $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
         $total = $order->calculate_totals();

         if (!$total > 'YOUR MINIMUM AMOUNT HERE') {
             wc_add_notice( 'You did not meet the minimum order total.', 'error' );
             exit;
         }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'check_min_order',  1, 1  );
```

Add this to your functions.php

I might have the $total variable being set using the wrong command. But this should give you a general idea of how to acheive this. It interupts the order process and checks the total to see if it meets your minimum amount. You can create a series of if statements or a switch statement for each case in your form fields. Whatever the name of the request object for the city is you can use `$_REQUEST['your_city_field_name']` to get the value.

If the condition is met then it will return a woocommerce formatted error and stop the processing of the transaction. If not it will continue as normal.

Comment: Thank you. I Will try to do this.